# Определить чему равно хэш-значение для строки, если известно что salt статическое

Tags: криптография

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить задачу, хочется объяснение услышать
Правильный ответ 254

## От редактора

Код функции `hashCRC` на Python:

```
def hashCRC(arg: str, 
            salt: str = "", 
            N: int = 256) -> int:
    res = 0
    for c in arg:
        res += ord(c)
    for c in salt:
        res += ord(c)
    res %= N
    return res
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Эта "контрольная сумма" линейна по параметру `salt`, то есть

```
hashCRC("some", salt) - hashCRC("same", salt) == hashCRC("some") - hashCRC("same")
```

Без учёта соли:

```
hashCRC("password") == 115
hashCRC("security") == 120
```

Поэтому `hashCRC("security", salt) == hashCRC("password", salt) + 5`, то есть `254`